# Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getElementsByTagName() PHP

Tags: php, xml

I've an XML file like the following:

```
<subject KL="1">
    <subjectName>If-Else</subjectName>
    <theory>
       <tutorial>...</tutorial>
       <full>...</full>
    </theory>
</subject>
```

and I try to extract it with the following PHP code:

```
$subjects = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "subject" );
foreach( $subjects as $subject ) {
      $knowledgeLevel = $subject->getAttribute( "KL" );
      $names = $subject->getElementsByTagName( "subjectName" );
      $name = $names->item(0)->nodeValue;

      $theory = $subject->getElementsByTagName( "theory" );
      $shorts = $theory->getElementsByTagName( "tutorial" );
      $short = $shorts->item(0)->nodeValue;
      $longs = $theory->getElementsByTagName( "full" );
      $long = $longs->item(0)->nodeValue;

      $subs [] = array (
            'knowledgeLevel' => $knowledgeLevel,
            'name' => $name,
            'shortTheory' => $short,
            'longTheory' => $long
      );
}
```

but my browser give me the error

```
Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getElementsByTagName()
```

in the line 8 of the code snippet. I don't get why it shouldn't work. Any help?

Answer (score 4):

sample to use getElementsByTagName

```
$xml = <<< XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<subject KL="1">
    <subjectName>If-Else</subjectName>
    <theory>
       <tutorial>...</tutorial>
       <full>...</full>
    </theory>
</subject>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$books = $dom->getElementsByTagName('subject');
foreach ($books as $book) {
    echo $book->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

try this in your loop

```
$theory = $subject->getElementsByTagName( "theory" );
$tutorial = $theory->item(0)->getElementsByTagName( "tutorial" )->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: the update is useful.. thank you! I had this already solved btw.

Comment: I hate people like you, @Jannuzzo. He tried to help you wasting HIS time and you mocked his answer because it was not of your taste? A big eff-u to you, really.

Comment: a "thank you but i already explained that in my original question" would have carried the same meaning but with a polite attitude. But i guess that's too hard for you and your like to comprehend.

Answer (score 3):

But the DOMNodeList doesn't have that method.

`getElementsByTagName` is part of the DOMDocument class